# How to Change ClassName after location.href() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I Need To Change The ClassName of `body` in HTML after using `location.href()`

```
location.href = "index.html";
document.querySelector("body").className = "whiteBackgroundColor";
```

^^^ Does Not Work :(

Comment: Changing location.href will navigate you away from the page. Why would you need to do something after that?

Comment: I want to Change The Class of the body tag, its like a theme switcher

Comment: A theme switcher for a page that's going away?

Comment: You can't affect the "next" page like that, if that's what you're planning.

Comment: then, can you suggest a way to do it?

Comment: You could store the user's color preference in localStorage and apply it on each page at load time.

Comment: Database? or liek JSON?

Comment: i'm new to web dev

Comment: Google localStorage for details.

Comment: okay, Thanks a Lot

Comment: `location.href` changes the page and the next lines of code will not execute. Only way you can do this is by writing logic in `onload` of the page that is redirected to.

Comment: In case it's temporary, use session storage instead. session storage data will stay until browser close.

Answer (score -1):

Use this JavaScript statement to set class to body

```
if(!document.body.classList.contains("whiteBackgroundColor"))
{
    document.body.classList.add("whiteBackgroundColor");
}
```

Comment: This code is verified and works perfectly to set class to body, may I know what's wrong with it?

Comment: Did you read the question, or in other words try how your code works after a statement that sets `location.href`?

Comment: Also, your code does unnecessary work - you can just call `classList.add` even if the class is already there; it won't be added twice or more.

Comment: What unnecessary and what's the use of classList.contains then, even classList.add checks if class is already applied or not only then it applies class. otherwise it could have end up in applying class more than one times

Comment: No, it does not apply it more than once. [The docs for `DOMTokenList#add` say "adds the given tokens to the list, omitting any that are already present"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/add). Because of that, you don't need to do `.contains()` manually if all you'd end up conditionally doing is `.add()`.